# Chromecast Android SDK: RemoteMediaPlayer always ends in IllegalStateException when trying to control

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to add media controls to my app but I can't get the RemoteMediaPlayer to send commands.
The video starts playing but then I can't control it.
This is the code I use:

```
RemoteMediaPlayer mRemoteMediaPlayer = new RemoteMediaPlayer();
                try {
    Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(apiClient, mRemoteMediaPlayer.getNamespace(), mRemoteMediaPlayer);

                        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
                        JSONObject jsonExtra = new JSONObject();
                        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "My video");

                        if (mediaType != null) {
                            jsonExtra.put("type", mediaType);
                        }
                        if ("audio".equals(mediaType)) {
                            mimeType = "audio/mp3";
                        }
                        com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaInfo.Builder builder = new MediaInfo.Builder(getUrl()).setContentType(mimeType).setMetadata(mediaMetadata).setCustomData(jsonExtra);
                        builder.setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED);

                        MediaInfo mediaInfo = builder.build();
                        mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(apiClient, mediaInfo, true, inititalTime).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(MediaChannelResult result) {
                                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    log(context, "Media loaded successfully");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                         mRemoteMediaPlayer.pause(apiClient);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    log(context, "Problem occurred with media during loading " + e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log(context, "Problem occurred with media during loading " + e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    log(context, "Problem occurred with media during loading " + e);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

You may notice that at the end I wait 5 seconds to make sure that the video is playing and then try to pause it.
This always results in an IllegalStateException with the message:

> No current media session

Am I missing something?
I also notice that the ResultCallback is never called after the video starts playing. Maybe this is also related to the same issue I'm experiencing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear when you are running this piece of code. Do not set a sleep like you did; you have to register callbacks on `mRemoteMediaPlayer` to be notified when status or metadata changes on the remote player. When the status changed listener is called, get the updated status by calling `mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus().getPlayerState()` and based on the status (whether it is playing, buffering, idle, paused), make the appropriate decision. In asynchronous systems, never use "sleep()", always hook into the callbacks.

Comment: Thanks Ali Naddaf, but as I mentioned, my callback is not being called. Is the code above not enough to receive the callbacks? The code is very similar to the one here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender I'm calling this after I've connected to the chromecast and my receiver app is launched and ready to play. This is in the onResult method in a class that implements ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: You are mixing two different callbacks; the PendingResult callback that you show above is just from the framework telling you that the command was sent. The other callback that I am talking about is set using mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(..) and mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnMetadataUpdatedListener(..) and those report back the updated in player status or metadata as they happen on the receiver side.

Comment: Thanks, those callbacks work. :) But the original problem still remains. I always get "No current media session" when trying to do mRemoteMediaPlayer.pause(apiClient);. Is there anything else I'm missing for this to work? When exactly can I use the remote player controls? Do I need to wait for a certain status update?

Comment: Something is not quite on your side and code, otherwise you shouldn't get that. I recommend one of the sample from our github and start from there to familiarize yourself with the flow and where and when things should/could be called.